# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'connectSSL'

Tags: python, ssl, openssl, twisted, pyqt4

I am programming a ssl client to my server where it uses python twisted with pyqt4, I used QTReactor for twisted in PYQT but when I run the code there is an error

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'connectSSL'
```

my initial code it like this

```
from OpenSSL import SSL
import sys
from twisted.internet.protocol import ClientFactory
from twisted.protocols.basic import LineReceiver
from twisted.internet import ssl
import qt4reactor

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
reactor=qt4reactor.install()
main()
myapp = MainForm()
myapp.show()
reactor.runReturn()
sys.exit(app.exec_())

def main():
    factory = ClientFactory()
    reactor.connectSSL('localhost', 8080, factory, ssl.ClientContextFactory())
    try:
        reactor.run()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        reactor.stop()
```

the error when i run it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "client.py", line 51, in <module>
    main()
  File "client.py", line 40, in main
    reactor.connectSSL('localhost', 8080, factory, ssl.ClientContextFactory())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'connectSSL'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'connectSSL'

is the error message that you get when you try to invoke a method on `None`.

This line of code

```
reactor=qt4reactor.install()
```

is the only place where `reactor` is assigned. The error message makes it clear that `reactor` is being assigned the value `None`.

All the web search hits that I can find on the topic follow this pattern:

```
qt4reactor.install(app)
from twisted.internet import reactor
```

and so I guess that's how you are meant to do it. But I do confess to knowing precisely nothing about these frameworks.

Answer (score 2):

`qt4reactor.install()` doesn't return a value so that `reactor` ends up being `None`. So when you attempt to call a method of `reactor` you get this error (obviously, `None` doesn't have any methods). If I see it correctly, the proper way of getting the `reactor` variable is this:

```
qt4reactor.install(app)
from twisted.internet import reactor
```